# trigger a child thread to awake from sleep whenever there is an insertion in the SqLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using SqLite database in Android. And there is a child thread that processes all the requests in one of the table in database. So whenever the table is empty, I want to put the thread to sleep and when there is a insertion into the table, I would like to wake the thread to process the requests. Is it possible? Please provide some code help

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem using either `SQLDelight` or [`Room`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)

Example:

```
interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table")
    LiveData<List<MyObject>> watchMyObjects();
}
```

This will emit a new list of objects whenever your database is modified.